# Why is the LTspice transformer failing to step up?

Tags: transformer, ltspice, simulation

I am simulating a basic pair of coupled inductors in LTspice. I have a 1HZ 2V peak AC wave on the input. The primary coil is 4uH with 1ohm parasitic resistance and the secondary coil is 20uH with 0ohm parasitic resistance. L2/L1=(N2/N1)^2 so we can say the turns ratio is sqrt(20uH/4uH)=2.236. However, when I simulate I find that the AC wave is stepped down from 2V peak to around 110uV peak which is very strange. Can anybody please help explain this?

[image: Primary vs secondary voltage]

[image: Secondary voltage]

Comment: What is the L/R time constant of 4uH with 1 ohm ESR?

Comment: For 1Hz you need a briefcase-sized inductor. Microhenries won’t cut it.

Comment: @smitty you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk offer free help.

Answer (score 4):

> *The primary coil is 4uH with 1ohm parasitic resistance*

Here's the problem.

Your input excitation voltage has a frequency of 1 Hz hence, at this frequency, 4 μH has a reactance of 25 μΩ AND, the voltage developed across it IS NOT 2 volts peak but around 50 μV peak.

That is the voltage applied to your inductor that couples to your secondary so, with a turns ratio of 2.236 you get a peak output voltage of 112 μV: -

[image]

Look familiar?

<sub>When you have digested this you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give their time for free and what you need to do to terminate this Q and A session. Please retrospectively apply what you learn there to your previous questions too.</sub>

Comment: 25 μΩ, surely, not 25 μH?

Comment: @Hearth oops yes and fixed.